# cancel all subscriptions in componentWillUnmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

each 5s the state is updated,
i know i cant update the state in componentWillUnmount , but i cant stop the update when i change the page.
How can i stop the update when i leave the page?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class RandomText extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoad: true,
    }
  }
  _isMounted = false;

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    this.onLoad();
  }

  onLoad = () => {
    const { isLoad } = this.state;
    if (this._isMounted === true) {
      if (isLoad !== true) {
        setTimeout(() => { this.setState({ isLoad: !this.state.isLoad }) }, 5000)
      }
      if (isLoad === true) {
        setTimeout(() => { this.setState({ isLoad: !this.state.isLoad }) },5000)
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { isLoad } = this.state;
    if (isLoad !== prevState.isLoad) {
      this.onLoad();
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoad }=this.state;
    return (
      <div className='landing'>
        <div className='landingInfo' >
```

here its change the class base on the state

```
          <p className={isLoad ? 'classOne' : 'classTwo'}>Text here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default RandomText;
```

Thank you!!

Comment: `setTimeout` returns a handle, you will want to call `clearTimeout` on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

Assign each setTimeout to a variable and clear them in componentWillUnMount using clearTimeout method like below

```
    onLoad = () => {
         const { isLoad } = this.state;
         if (this._isMounted === true) {
               if (isLoad !== true) {
                    this.timeout1 = setTimeout(() => {      this.setState({ isLoad: !this.state.isLoad }) }, 5000)
                    }
               if (isLoad === true) {
                     this.timeout2 = setTimeout(() => { this.setState({ isLoad: !this.state.isLoad }) },5000)
               }
           }
       }

  componentWillUnMount(){
        this._isMounted = false;
        clearTimeout(this.timeout1);
        clearTimeout(this.timeout2);
  }
```